# Why does State need a value?

Tags: haskell, monads

Just learning about State monad from this excellent [tutorial](http://brandon.si/code/the-state-monad-a-tutorial-for-the-confused/). However, when I tried to explain it to a non-programmer they had a question that stumped me.

If the purpose of the State is to simulate mutable memory, why is the function that state monad stores is of the type:

```
s -> (a, s)
```

and not simply:

```
s -> s
```

In other words, what is the need for the "intermediate" value? For example, couldn't we, in the cases where we need it, simulate it by simply defining a state as a tuple of `(state, value)`?

I'm sure I confused something, any help is appreciated.

Comment: I like Roman's answer, but I would say that the purpose of `State` is not to simulate mutable memory, but to simulate computations that require mutable memory.  The point of running `State` is (notionally) to obtain the result of the computation, with the state itself being simply an artifact.  Of course in real problems we often do care about the output state, which is why it's available too.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To draw a parallel with an imperative language like C, `s -> s` corresponds to a function with the return type `void`, which is invoked purely for side effects (such as mutating the memory). It is isomorphic to `State s ()`.

And indeed, it is possible to write C functions which communicate only through global variables. But, as in C, it is often convenient to return values from functions. That's what `a` is for.

Of course it's possible that for your particular problem `s -> s` is a better choice. Although it's not a Monad, it is a Monoid (when wrapped in [Endo](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-Monoid.html#v:Endo)). So you can construct such functions using `<>` and `mempty`, which correspond to `>>=` and `return` of Monad.

Comment: Also `s -> s` doesn't scale very well. Using your C parallel: you can always add extra information into global state by simply defining new global variable; in Haskell this would require changing the underlying type `s`. I'll illustrate with an example: let's have a state `Stack -> Stack` and we'd like to collect how the top of stack looks at some specific moments. In C, you could just add new global variable, with `Stack -> Stack` you can't - you have to use something more specific such as `(Stack,[a]) -> (Stack,[a])`. With "normal" state it is as simple as using few `<-` and `return [a,b,c]`

Comment: Sorry, but I gave this answer a -1. I worry that, although true and indeed powerful, the Monoid view of functions is likely to be more confusing to a new Haskell developer learning about `State` than helpful. Initially it's simplest to treat function composition directly as function composition (or `Control.Category.(.)` if you want to be somewhat more general) than as monoid append.

Answer (score 5):

To expand a bit on Nick's answer:

`s` is the state. If all your functions were `s -> s` (state to state), your functions would not be able to return any values. You could define your state as `(the actual state, value returned)`, but that conflates the state with the value the state-ful functions are computing. And it's also the common case that you'll want functions to actually compute and return values...

Answer (score 2):

Presumably you want to use your stateful computations inside of `do` notation?

You should ask yourself what the `Monad` instance would look like for a stateful computation defined by

```
newtype State s = { runState :: s -> s }
```

Comment: It is perhaps more enlightening to think about how you would write the `Functor` instance. `fmap :: (a -> b) -> State a -> State b`. While you can easily transform the "output" end of State, you do not have enough information to also transform the input end.

Comment: I originally ended the answer with "In fact, what would the `Functor` instance look like?" but decided not to include it :)

Answer (score 2):

`s' -> s'` is equivalent to `(a, s) -> (a, s)`. Here it is obvious that your `State` will need an initial `a` to start things off in addition to `s`.

On the other hand `s -> (a, s)` only needs the seed `s` to begin things and does not require an `a` value at all.

Thus the type of `s -> (a, s)` tells you that `State` is less complex than if it were `(a, s) -> (a, s)`. Types in Haskell convey LOTS of information.

Answer (score 2):

> If the purpose of the `State` is to simulate mutable memory, why is the function that state monad stores is of the type:
>
> ```
> s -> (a, s)
> ```
>
> and not simply:
>
> ```
> s -> s
> ```

The purpose of the `State` monad is not to simulate mutable memory, but rather to model computations that *both* produce a value *and* have a side effect. Simply, given some initial state of type `s`, your computation will produce some value of type `a`, as well as an updated state.

Maybe your computation does not produce a value... Then, easy: the value type `a` is simply `()`.  Perhaps on the other hand your computation does not have a side effect.  Again, easy: you might think of your state transition function (the `s -> s` argument to `modify`) as just being `id`.  But often you're dealing with both at the same time.

---

You can actually use `get` and `put` as relatively simple examples:

```
get :: State s s      -- s -> (s, s)
put :: s -> State ()  -- s -> (s -> ((), s))
```

- `get` is a computation which, given the current state (the first `s`), will return it both as a value -- that is, the result of the computation -- and as the "new" (unmodified) state.
- `put` is a computation which, given a new state (the first `s`) and a current state (the second `s`), will simply *ignore* the current state. It will produce `()` as the computed value (because, of course, it hasn't computed any value!) and hang onto the new state provided.

Answer (score 2):

The problem to be solved is that you have an input and a series of functions, and you want to apply the functions to the input in order.

If the functions are purely state-changing functions, `s -> s` on an input of type `s`, then you don't *need* `State` to use them. Haskell is very good at chaining together functions like these, e.g. with the standard composition operator `.`, or something like `foldr (.) id`, or `foldr id`.

However, if the functions both mutate a state *and* report some result of doing so, so that you could give them the type `s -> (s,a)`, then gluing them all together is a bit of a nuisance. You have to unpack the result tuple and pass the new state value to the next function, use the reported value somewhere else, and then unpack *that* result, and so on. It's easy to pass the wrong state to an input function because you have to name each result and input explicitly to do the unpacking. You end up with something like this:

```
let
  (res1, s1) = fun1 s0
  (res2, s2) = fun2 s1
  (res3, s3) = fun3 res1 res2 s1
  ...
  in resN
```

There, I accidentally passed `s1` instead of `s2`, maybe because I added the second line in later and didn't realise the third line needed changing. When composing the `s -> s` functions, this problem can't possibly arise because there are no names to get right:

```
let
  resN = fun1 . fun2 . fun3 . -- etc.
```

So we invented `State` to do the same trick. `State` is essentially just a way of gluing functions like `s -> (s,a)` together in such a way that the right state always gets passed to the right function.

So it's not so much that people went "we want to use `State`, let's use `s -> (s,a)`" but rather "we're writing functions like `s -> (s,a)`, let's invent `State` to make that easy". With functions `s -> s`, it's already easy and we don't have to invent anything.

As an example of how `s -> (s,a)` arises naturally, consider parsing: a parser will be given some input, consume some of the input and return a value. In Haskell, this is naturally modelled as taking an input list, and returning a pair of the value and the remaining input - i.e. `[Input] -> ([Input], a)`, or `State [Input]`.

Answer (score -1):

`a` is the value returned, and the `s` is the final state.

http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/State_Monad#Implementation